# Apply transformation matrix around the center of an element

Tags: html, canvas, svg, transform, canvg

I am using Raphael to make some manipulations in SVG.
In order to save the SVG as image i use Canvg to render the SVG in canvas.
But the transformations of images inside the SVG rendered in canvas is not right.
Canvg uses native transform() method of html5 to apply the transformations using the below code in line 571 of Canvg.

```
ctx.transform(this.m[0], this.m[1], this.m[2], this.m[3], this.m[4], this.m[5]);
```

But this results in transformations like rotations and scaling done around the origin of the image.
But in Raphael the transformations are applied around the center of the image.

So is it possible to apply transformations so everything happens around center of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function that makes transformations happen around the center of the image given the image's **center points**.

The theory around making things transform by its center is as follows :

1. Translate the image by **`<-X,-Y,-Z>`**, where (X,Y,Z) is the image's center.
2. Do the transformation you want to do
3. Translate the image by **`<X,Y,Z>`**. (You're just returning it back to its original position now)

Comment: I tried that . I used `ctx.translate(cx, cy);` before transformations where cx and cy is the center of the image but doesn't show any difference.The image get's rotated and scaled around the origin.

Comment: You have to translate the **negative** of the center of the image before you do the transformations. 

So you have to do `ctx.translate(-cx,-cy)`.
Then do your transformations.
Then revert it back by using `ctx.translate(cx,cy).

Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: the ctx.translate will have no effect when followed by a ctx.setTransform. The computations have to be performed on a matrix.

Comment: The svg i was having was throwing an error **TypeError: this.transforms[i].unapply** when renedred using canvg and canvg i am using has some modifications done by me to tackel this problem.So i am unable to load this in the jsfiddle which has the native canvg file. I think the change made by me is causing the problem somehow.Because when i remove the paths and tried it in canvg the image transformations are correct which can be seen in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/683/!

I have logged it as a bug https://code.google.com/p/canvg/issues/detail?id=287.

Comment: @GameAlchemist we are not using ctx.setTransform, but simply applying the transformation matrix values using ctx.transform().

Comment: yes my bad i meant : ctx.transform. When using this, it will override any previous transform. So you have to perform @MarkGabriel 's proposal on the matrix, then use transform() with this computed matrix to really give his answer a try.